# How can I grep for empty functions?

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

I'm recursively looking in a directory for all functions containing only a blank one-line comment, such as the following:

```
public function index()
{
    //
}
```

I tried `grep -PR "//$" *` with no luck.

Comment: Doesn't `grep -PR "^\s*//\s*$" *` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `grep` is only matching `//` that are at the very end of the line. Your functions probably have whitespace characters after that. You might also want to allow whitespace before the `//`. so search for lines that consist entirely of 0 or more whitespace characters, then the `//` and then 0 or more whitespace characters:

```
grep -PR '^\s*//\s*$'
```